# Can I get nvlink to list the libraries it actually used?

Tags: cuda, linker, linker-flags

`nvlink` can be given search paths for libraries with the `-L <path>` option, and a bunch of libraries to consider with `-lmylib1` `-lmiylib2` etc.

Can `nvlink` be made to list the (full paths of the) libraries it *actually* used during linking?

Comment: don't believe so, no

Comment: @talonmies: I was actually hoping to use that list to resolve [this mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59481008/1593077).

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can (on GNU/Linux) use the [`ltrace`](https://www.ltrace.org/) or [`strace`](https://strace.io/) utilities and determine all files which nvlink opened. This is a superset of what it actually used, but it's better than just "some files in directory ".