# Why does nvcc refuse to link this simple cooperative-groups program?

Tags: cuda, linker, linker-errors, ptxas, gpu-cooperative-groups

Consider the following CUDA program, in a file named `foo.cu`:

```
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void my_kernel() {
    auto g = cooperative_groups::this_grid();
    g.sync();
}

int main(int, char **) {
    cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel( (const void*) my_kernel, 2, 2, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

This program doesn't do much - but it's a valid program (if your compute capability is high enough to support the entire grid as a cooperative group). It should compile link and run. However, I get this:

```
$ nvcc -o foo  -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 foo.cu 
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'cudaCGGetIntrinsicHandle'
```

Surprising! It doesn't help if I add some specific `-l` and `-L` flags, e.g.:

```
$ nvcc -o foo  -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 foo.cu -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" \
-L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs"  -lcudadevrt -lcudart_static -lrt -lpthread -ldl
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'cudaCGGetIntrinsicHandle'
```

Why is this happening? And how should I modify the nvcc command-line to make it find that unresolved symbol?

Notes:

- I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux 3.0.
- CUDA 10.1 is installed as a distribution package, so that its libraries are under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.
- An x86_64 machine with a GeForce 1050 Ti card.

Comment: cooperative groups with grid sync requires relocatable device code linking.  If you look at any of the CUDA sample codes that do this, you'll find a properly constructed Makefile which indicates how to build.  So add `-rdc=true` to  your compile command line.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Adding `-rdc=true` doesn't solve the problem, but adding `-rdc=true` _and_ all those `-L` and `-l`s does.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: See [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481689/why-does-my-nvcc-refuse-to-look-into-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: In a supported development environment, according to my testing, the only thing required to compile this code is: `nvcc -arch=sm_60 -o t1 t1.cu -rdc=true -lcudadevrt`  (the `arch` switch can be changed to any arch that supports grid sync, which should be cc6.0 or higher)